# CSS how translate DIV with whole content in it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, transform

I'm trying to **translate in 90 degrees** a `div` with it all content (images and text), how can I do that?

I tried this css but no success :

```css
div.ccw {
         transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(540px); 
         -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(540px); 
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(540px);
        -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(540px);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(540px);
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-view=""  class="container-fluid main-screen ng-scope ccw"><div class="error row ng-scope">
 <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
  <div class="padding-3percent logo col-xs-12 text-center">
   <img class="img-responsive center-block" width="60px" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plu/JPSimulatorHacks/master/Data/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="padding-2percent logo col-xs-12 text-center">
   <img width="60px" class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plu/JPSimulatorHacks/master/Data/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
   <h1>TEST</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
   <strong>Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test</strong> 
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
   <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
    <p>
     Test test Test testTest test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test testTest testTest test
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="text-right col-xs-12">
    <span>counter</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div></div>
```

Many thanks

Comment: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/ looks interesting, but I haven't tried it.  According to http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_rotation.asp, the range for rotation is 0 to 360, so try replacing -90 with 270.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does work, but since the coordinate system is rotated too by 90 degrees (so as X becomes Y and Y becomes X), you are now translating not forwards, but upwards, and the div gets out of your view. Change `translateX` to `translateY` (I also reduced the translation value since the demo window is small):

```css
div.ccw {
   transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(240px); 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-view=""  class="container-fluid main-screen ng-scope ccw"><div class="error row ng-scope">
 <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
  <div class="padding-3percent logo col-xs-12 text-center">
   <img class="img-responsive center-block" width="60px" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plu/JPSimulatorHacks/master/Data/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="padding-2percent logo col-xs-12 text-center">
   <img width="60px" class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plu/JPSimulatorHacks/master/Data/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
   <h1>TEST</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
   <strong>Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test</strong> 
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
   <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
    <p>
     Test test Test testTest test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test testTest testTest test
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="text-right col-xs-12">
    <span>counter</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! can you tell me the diff btw x axis and y axis in this case?(sorry by noobness)

Comment: @Alvaro But you've rotated the coordinate system by 90 degs. X is now Y and Y is now X.

Comment: @Alvaro Draw XY system on the sheet of paper and rotate the sheet by 90 degrees :)

Comment: Hey can you help me in this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869681/css-how-make-the-page-full-height-and-width-when-rotate-body :)