# SASS How make the page full height and width when rotated body?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, rotation

I'm have to rotate my body and make it **full height** and **full width**.

Well, I used the **vh** metric and worked perfect for **width**, but height still not fitting well...

I had to **rotate 90 degrees** but the **height** and **width** still referring the same orientation as **not** rotate.

Ps: I added `.red` to be easier to see where the `div/body` is fitting.

> All I want is the rotated content fit the whole page/size of available the window

### EDIT

I just found out that there is an way of doing it by computing `sin` and `cos`, 
I wonder if the **SASS** can do it ? In an more automate/lazy way ?

Please refer the snippet:

```css
div.ccw {
         transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(0px); 
         -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(0px); 
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(0px);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(0px);
    }
.main-screen{
width:100vh; 
  height:100vh;
}
.red{
background-color:red;
}
#footer{
  
}
#footer {
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-view=""  class="red container-fluid main-screen ng-scope ccw"><div class="error row ng-scope">
 <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
  <div class="padding-3percent logo col-xs-12 text-center">
   <img class="img-responsive center-block" width="60px" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plu/JPSimulatorHacks/master/Data/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="padding-2percent logo col-xs-12 text-center">
   <img width="60px" class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plu/JPSimulatorHacks/master/Data/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
   <h1>TEST</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
   <strong>Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test</strong> 
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
   <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
    <p>
     Test test Test testTest test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test testTest testTest test
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="text-right col-xs-12">
    <span>counter</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div></div>
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: @nicael please can you help me in this one?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276467/adjusting-div-width-and-height-after-rotated It might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your CSS should use vw for height and vh for width since in the rotated state the CSS values still refer to the original positioning. So:

```
.main-screen{
    width:100vh; 
    height:100vw;
}
```

Once you apply that, the dimensions of your red box should match the dimensions of the viewport.

There's a second problem to deal with, though. When something rotates, by default it rotates around its center. As a result, with rectangular elements (width and height are different), rotating around the center moves the element to a different position on the page.

You would need to use the `tranform-origin` CSS property to offset this effect. `transform-origin` changes the point of origin for a transformation, in this case the point around which the element is rotating.

When rotating an element of a fixed size, you could offset the movement using this property pretty easily. Unfortunately, I haven't yet figured out how to set `tranform-origin` so that it works with an element of variable size, as in this case. This may be something you would have to use JavaScript for (or maybe someone more creative than me could find a CSS- or SASS-only option).

For more on transform-origin, see: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-origin/

And: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

**Edit**

Try this and let me know if it does what you want. First, we're setting the width and height as described above (width:100vh; height:100vw;). Then, instead of trying to calculate a transform-origin that can compensate for any given width as speculated above, we're making the box rotate around it's top left axis, then using absolute positioning on the box to shift the position 100% down from the top of the viewport (i.e., pushing the box down 1x its length so that it's back in position).

```css
div.ccw {
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(0px); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(0px); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(0px);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
.main-screen{
    width:100vh; 
    height:100vw;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
}
.red{
    background-color:red;
}
#footer{
  
}
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-view=""  class="red container-fluid main-screen ng-scope ccw"><div class="error row ng-scope">
 <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
  <div class="padding-3percent logo col-xs-12 text-center">
   <img class="img-responsive center-block" width="60px" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plu/JPSimulatorHacks/master/Data/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="padding-2percent logo col-xs-12 text-center">
   <img width="60px" class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plu/JPSimulatorHacks/master/Data/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
   <h1>TEST</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
   <strong>Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test</strong> 
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
   <div class="text-center col-xs-12">
    <p>
     Test test Test testTest test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test test Test testTest testTest test
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="text-right col-xs-12">
    <span>counter</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Can you try to solve my snippet? I guess you exp in this would be enough to solve this quickly :)

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer and let me know if it works for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is also a unit vw. 100vw is equal to 100% of viewport width so you could use:

```
.main-screen{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
}
```